# Detect if onStop is called due to a notification starting a new intent presenting a new activity or before destroy()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I have a timer running on an activityA, during this timer a notification may appear and a user clicking on a button on it will fire a new intent which pushes a new activityB hiding the current one activityA.

I have to stop the timer in activityA only if its onStop() is called before ondestroy() due to the new activityB coming on top (users clicks on notification and fires the intent), and not by a change of visibility status (eg: user pressing home button/power button).

I can stop the timer on onstop() but this will stop the timer in every condition (new intent from notification, screen turned off, power button pressed)

I can stop the timer on ondestroy() but this way prevents stopping the timer when presenting another activityB.

I was thinking about a way to stop the timer accessing the activityA navigating the stack on activityB.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a `BroadcastReceiver` in `activityA`, which the notification intent can trigger. In there, stop your timer and launch `activityB`.

Note that if your timer is a field of `activityA`, it may be destroyed if `activityA` is in the background. If this is a problem, consider keeping the timer in a foreground `Service`, or using an alarm instead.